# Conditional XML edittext format

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to conditionally format a widget using only XML layout files?

For example: If the value of an `EditText` is < 10, write it in red, otherwise write it green. Here is the Java code:

```java
// Code
if (Integer.parseInt(edTxt.getText().toString()) < 10){
    edTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}else{
    edTxt.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}
//or
edTxt.setTextColor (Integer.parseInt (edTxt.getText().toString()) < 10 ? Color.RED:Color.GREEN);
```

And put "this code" inside XML?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it's impossible.

Comment: Why do you want to try something like that? Is it necessary for you??

Comment: If you want to change the text color of the editText whenever you type something use TextWatcher. If you need this behaviour in large no of occurrences then go for a customized editText.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done if you extend the EditText to a custom view and there do the logic.
You can also use attributes to enter the values for comparison, and the colors.